# Unstable Algorithms which become stable when hardware provides Kulisch exact dot product instruction

Tags: linear-algebra, numerics, floating-point

In John Gustaffson's book [The End of Error](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00S9OM68I), he discusses Ulrich Kulisch's [exact dot product](https://wg25.taa.univie.ac.at/ifip/projects/Poster22.pdf), which (in double precision) requires a 2100 bit fixed point register which rounds only once after the computation of the dot product is complete.

I have found only one statement about how this instruction can be used in numerical analysis, namely Kulish claims "it is the EDP which makes residual correction effective . . " However, I could not find a reference demonstrating this claim.

What numerical methods would benefit from an exact dot product? And more interestingly, are there algorithms which *become* stable in the presence of a hardware dot product which are unstable otherwise?

Comment: I think the classical Gram-Schmidt algorithm is one of them. Except for some simple cases, it is not stable under floating point arithmetic, but the issue can be fixed by reordering the operations -called Modified Gram-Schmidt- (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1676362). I don't know many algorithms that fail only due to errors coming from dot products, but it is a source of error and getting rid of a source of error is always good.

Comment: The poster has the sentence "This has a direct and positive influence on all iterative solvers of systems of equations." so this would actually be beneficial for all Krylov subspace methods as an example.

Comment: I know I am putting a lot of comments and probably I should combine all to an answer; but here are more links that are relevant: https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/02/16/iterative-refinement-for-solutions-to-linear-systems/#858cef39-84a1-4bb1-9504-c943a2fbecbc and https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2015/03/02/triple-precision-accumlated-inner-product/

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas: Nice link! Cleve is doing essentially the same thing in software as Kulisch wanted in hardware.

Comment: The poster has a very simple example that fails under double precision arithmetic, but is stable under exact dot products: $x_{n+1}=3.75  x_n (1-x_n), x_0 = 0.5$